# How to place leaflet geocoder control on a page where there is no map?

Tags: leaflet, geocoding, react-leaflet

I have a project with `React` where I use Leaflet to render a map. I use `leaflet geocoder` to look up locations on the map. I want to show the search box on the homepage too where there is no map, but when people choose some place, it will take them to that location on the map. The only problem I have is all the geocoder libraries on leaflet work only when the control is tied to the map. Is there anyway to make it independent from the map?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out `leaflet-geosearch` library ([here](https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch/#installation)) has the ability to be used without being embedded in a map. You can embed it in any form, without few lines of code. I'm using React.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {OpenStreetMapProvider} from 'leaflet-geosearch'

const SearchBox = () => {
      const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
      const [results, setResults] = useState([])

      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const results = await provider.search({ query: text });
      setSearchResult(results)
  }
  return (
    <>
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
     </form>
     <div>
      {searchResults.map(item => <p>{item.label}</p>}
     </div>
    </>
   )
}

export default SearchBox;
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.